# Identify heads, specifiers, complements and adjuncts in this sentence

Tags: syntax

Hi could someone help me to identify the different elements cited above in the sentence below:

> so completely out [of control of the situation]

No need to analyse the words inside the bracketed PP.

Thank you very much

Comment: It doesn't seem obvious to me that [of control of the situation] is a constituent. Could you explain this please?

Comment: Hi missbubulle, welcome to the site. This looks like it may be homework. If it is, please show how you have attempted to answer the question. Otherwise you might not get an answer.

Comment: Not obvious to me that "so completely out [of control of the situation]" is a sentence, either.

Comment: I think the consensus is that until one controls the concepts of _head, specifier, complement,_ and _adjunct_ -- and can identify examples readily -- getting advice from anyone but your teacher about how they work in this string is not likely to be of any assistance. Many people use these terms differently, or not at all, and therefore I suggest you consult your teacher, because obviously you have been told that they are standard terms. Only your teacher can explain what concepts they represent in your class.